# Can't compile dll from C++ project - Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, dll, ffmpeg

I'm trying to play a RTSP stream in Unity 5.

For that I found a [RTSP-plugin](https://github.com/gujadot/RTSP_Unity_Plugin) for Unity on Github that I want to try, but unfortunatelly it comes with no Readme or installation guide whatsoever.

So far I found out that I'm dealing with a C++ Visual Studio project that needs to be compiled into a DLL in order to add it to Unity. But when I try to build the project I get the following Error for the header file "ffmpegenv.h":

*Error  C1083   Cannot open include file: 'libavutil\opt.h': No such file or directory* - [(Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC0sY.png)

Here's the code from the header file

```
#pragma once

//=============================
// Includes
//-----------------------------
// FFMPEG is writen in C so we need to use extern "C"
//-----------------------------
extern "C" {
    //#define INT64_C(x) (x ## LL)
    //#define UINT64_C(x) (x ## ULL)

#include <libavutil\opt.h>
#include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>

}
```

I'm aware that the header includes source code from the FFmpeg libraries which doesn't come with the plugin I'm trying to compile. So I downloaded the FFmpeg source code from their GitHub page and copied all the code files (with its original folder structure) inside the plugin's project folder.

However when I then try to compile the plugin, it still doesn't find the #includes an shows the same error as mentioned above.

How I can I get the plugin to compile? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

P.S.: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 with C++ support and Win 10 SDK as well as Win 8.1 SDK.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that "it won't build either"? What's the error? What do you mean that you have copied the libraries? Which files exactly have you copied and into which folder?

Comment: @KjMag I updated the description of my problem due to your question. I hope it becomes clearer.
Basically I get the same C1083 errors as I mentioned above although I copied ALL the FFmpeg files into the plugin's project folder.